# Card Attachments disappeared after Trello Update this morning!

Tags: trello

I updated my Trello today per the Notification, afterwards all my Card Attachments were gone.  Icon on the Card still shows the number of attachments for each card, however when I open a card, it states no attachments.  Anyone know of a bug?

Comment: Update on this.  I went back to start re-adding the attachments and when I upload 1 on a card, all missing attachments for that card reappear.  But I must then delete the one I just added as it is now a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you saw [this bug](https://trello.com/c/p0CMBiWu), which has since been fixed